# Evaluate gradient

Tags: calculus

I am trying to calculate wavefield displacement $u(x,z,t)$, that can be expressed as
$$u(x,z,t)=\nabla \phi(x,z,t) \tag1$$
using Helmholtz decomposition(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition). Note that only longitudinal component is considered here. Scalar potential $\phi(x,z,t)$ has form
$$\phi(x,z,t)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty }^\infty \frac{s(t-\frac{r}{a})}{r}dy \tag2$$ 
where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and $s(t-\frac{r}{a})=e^{-b(t-\frac{r}{a}-c)^2}$. Parameters $a,b,c$ are constants. Since $dy/r=dr/y$ and $r$ is even in $y$, we have
$$\phi(x,z,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{d }^\infty \frac{s(t-\frac{r}{a})}{y}dr =\frac{H(t-\frac{d}{a})}{2\pi}\int_{\frac{d}{a} }^t \frac{s(t-\tau)}{\sqrt{\tau^2-(\frac{d}{a})^2}}d\tau \tag3$$
where $H$ is a Heaviside step function and $d(x,z)=\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$.
These are the forms $(2)$ and $(3)$ of $\phi(x,z,t)$ written in a book I am using, but substitution of $(2)$ or $(3)$ into $(1)$  and very calculation of gradient of this scalar potential is not preformed there. I was thinking about applying Leibnitz integral rule on last expression in $(3)$, while integral has a variable lower limit, but integrand has a singularity at  $ \tau=\frac{d}{a} $. Could somebody help with calculation of function $u(x,z,t)$? Thank you in advance.